# Python splitting on a character properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using `list.split('&')` to split input like `thing1 & thing2 & thing3`, which works:

```
output: ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3']
```

But I need this also to be able to handle mistypes, such as `thing1 & thing2 &thing3`. Output:

```
Error: List must contain exactly 3 items.
```

How can I use a `.split()` to handle any and all variations of  , `&` and give me the list items I need? Which is any and all items separated by `&` with or without spaces.

I've tried all sorts of variations of `.split(' & ')` and  `.split(' &')`, none of which seem to work.

Comment: First, ou should not call your variable `list`. As for the question, your code is already splitting string `'thing1 & thing2 &thing3'` into three parts. However, both the "good" and the "bad" variant will result in spaces around words, which you need to `strip()`

Comment: `list` doesn't have a `split()` method. You mean `str.split()`, or is `list` the name of a string? That's confusing.

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided a [mre]. Your code doesn't reproduce the problem since `len('thing1 & thing2 &thing3'.split('&')) == 3`. And where's that error coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
items = "thing1 & thing2 &thing3"

[x.strip() for x in items.split("&")]

--> ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3']
```

Comment: Deneb is right, just split at the character, and then strip the whitespace afterwards

Answer (score 2):

`split` on the `&` on its own and then use `strip` to deal with the whitespace:

```
>>> msg = "thing1 & thing2 &thing3"
>>> [i.strip() for i in msg.split("&")]
['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3']
```

(do not name a variable `list`, you'll overwrite the builtin `list` function!)

Answer (score 2):

Split without using any spaces, then strip spaces away afterwards.

```
l = [s.strip() for s in mystring.split("&")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions (aka Regex) is an important tool you need to learn for your toolbox when dealing with strings.

Example:

```
import re

my_string = 'thing1 & thing2 &thing3'
my_list = re.split('\s*&\s*', my_string)
```

Here we look for space character (`\s`) 0 or many times, followed by `&`, then another space character 0 or many times.

Comment: "space character" is not quite right. It's any whitespace characters, including tabs, NBSPs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Regular expression (regex)

You could use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), though it's a bit overkill since the simpler tools work in this case, i.e. `str.split()` then `str.strip()`.

```
import re

for s in 'thing1 & thing2 & thing3', 'thing1 & thing2 &thing3':
    words = re.split(r'\s*\&\s*', s)
    print(words)
```

Output:

```
['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3']
['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3']
```

Breakdown:

- `\s` - Any whitespace character - space, tab, etc
- `*` - Zero or more of the preceding

(Ampersand is escaped with a backslash for forward compatibility. It might become a special character in the future.)